# How can I offset a Bounding Circle based on a rotation?

Tags: java, collision-detection, bounding-box

I am creating a Bullet projectile and giving it a Binding Circle with it. I am trying to set the circle to be at the front of the bullet so when it impacts it collides. Below is the bullet and a blue circle displaying the bounding circle location.

[image]

The bottom right example is what I am looking todo but with any rotation. Any thoughts on how I can offset the circle dynamically?

HitBox.java (This is the blue circle)

```
package com.icyrelic.game.object;

import com.icyrelic.game.object.entity.Entity;
import com.jogamp.opengl.math.VectorUtil;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;


public class HitBox {

    @Getter
    private GameObject object;
    @Getter @Setter
    private float width = 0, height = 0, xOffset = 0f, yOffset = 0f, radius = 0;


    public HitBox(GameObject object, float width, float height) {
        this.object = object;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    public HitBox(GameObject entity, float radius) {
        this.object = object;
        this.radius = radius;
    }


    public boolean intersects(HitBox b) {
        boolean collisionX = getMinX() <= b.getMaxX() && getMaxX() >= b.getMinX();
        boolean collisionY = getMinY() <= b.getMaxY() && getMaxY() >= b.getMinY();

        return collisionX && collisionY;
    }

    public boolean willCollide(HitBox b, float x, float y) {
        //Circle vs Circle
        if(radius != 0 && b.getRadius() != 0)
            return circleCollide(x, y, b.getRadius(), b.getXOffset(), b.getYOffset());

        //Circle vs AABB
        if((radius != 0 && b.getRadius() == 0) || (radius == 0 && b.getRadius() != 0))
            return circleAABBCollusion(b, x, y);

        //AABB vs AABB
        boolean collisionX = getMinX() <= x+b.getWidth()/2 && getMaxX() >= x-b.getWidth()/2;
        boolean collisionY = getMinY() <= y+b.getHeight()/2 && getMaxY() >= y-b.getHeight()/2;

        return collisionX && collisionY;
    }

    private boolean circleCollide(float x2, float y2, float radius2, float xOffset2, float yOffset2) {
        double xDif = (object.getLocation().getX() + xOffset) - (x2 + xOffset2);
        double yDif = (object.getLocation().getY() + yOffset) - (y2 + yOffset2);
        double distanceSquared = xDif * xDif + yDif * yDif;

       return distanceSquared < (radius + radius2) * (radius + radius2);
    }

    private boolean circleAABBCollusion(HitBox b, float x, float y) {
        HitBox circle = radius == 0 ? b : this;
        HitBox aabb = radius == 0 ? this : b;

        float[] circleCenter = radius == 0 ? new float[] {x, y} : new float[] {object.getLocation().getX(), object.getLocation().getY()};
        float[] aabbCenter = radius == 0 ? new float[] {object.getLocation().getX(), object.getLocation().getY()} : new float[] {x, y};

        float closestX = circleCenter[0] + circle.getXOffset();
        float closestY = circleCenter[1] + circle.getYOffset();

        if(closestX < aabb.getMinX(aabbCenter[0])) closestX = aabb.getMinX(aabbCenter[0]);
        else if (closestX > aabb.getMaxX(aabbCenter[0])) closestX = aabb.getMaxX(aabbCenter[0]);

        if(closestY < aabb.getMinY(aabbCenter[1])) closestY = aabb.getMinY(aabbCenter[1]);
        else if (closestY > aabb.getMaxY(aabbCenter[1])) closestY = aabb.getMaxY(aabbCenter[1]);

        float dist = VectorUtil.distSquareVec3(new float[]{circleCenter[0]+circle.getXOffset(), circleCenter[1]+circle.getYOffset(), 1}, new float[]{closestX, closestY, 1});

        return dist <= circle.getRadius() * circle.getRadius();
    }

    private float getMinX() { return object.getLocation().getX()+xOffset - width/2; }
    private float getMaxX() { return object.getLocation().getX()+xOffset + width/2; }
    private float getMinY() { return object.getLocation().getY()+yOffset - height/2; }
    private float getMaxY() { return object.getLocation().getY()+yOffset + height/2;}

    private float getMinX(float x) { return x+xOffset - width/2; }
    private float getMaxX(float x) { return x+xOffset + width/2; }
    private float getMinY(float y) { return y+yOffset - height/2; }
    private float getMaxY(float y) { return y+yOffset + height/2;}

    public void setSize(float width, float height) { this.width = width; this.height = height; }
    public void setOffset(float x, float y) { this.xOffset = x; this.yOffset = y; }
}
```

Bullet.java

```
package com.icyrelic.game.object.projectile.type;

import com.icyrelic.game.Graphics.Animation;
import com.icyrelic.game.Graphics.ImageResource;
import com.icyrelic.game.object.projectile.Projectile;


public class Bullet extends Projectile {

    public Bullet(float x, float y, float width, float height, float rotation, float rotationOffset) {
        super(x,y,width, height, rotation, rotationOffset);
        hitBox.setRadius(0.03f);
        hitBox.setYOffset(-0.12f);
        location.setRotationOffset(-0f);



        animations = new Animation[1];
        ImageResource[] a = new ImageResource[1];
        a[0] = new ImageResource("/Projectile/Bullet.png");

        animations[0] = new Animation(a, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void update() {
        //location.setRotation(0);
    }



}
```

Projectile.java

```
package com.icyrelic.game.object.projectile;

import com.icyrelic.game.Graphics.Graphics;
import com.icyrelic.game.object.GameObject;
import com.icyrelic.game.object.HitBox;
import lombok.Getter;


@Getter
public abstract class Projectile extends GameObject {

    protected float speed = 1.0f;
    protected HitBox hitBox;

    public Projectile(float x, float y, float width, float height, float rotation, float rotationOffset) {
        super(x, y, width, height, rotation, rotationOffset);
        this.hitBox = new HitBox(this, width, height);
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        super.render();
        Graphics.setColor(0,0, 1, 1);

        if(hitBox.getRadius() == 0) {
            Graphics.drawRect(location.getX() + hitBox.getXOffset(), location.getY() + hitBox.getYOffset(), hitBox.getWidth(), hitBox.getHeight(), false);
        } else {
            Graphics.drawHollowCircle(location.getX() + hitBox.getXOffset(), location.getY() + hitBox.getYOffset(), hitBox.getRadius());
        }
        Graphics.setColor(1,0, 0, 1);
        //Graphics.drawRect(location.getX(), location.getY(), width/2, height/2, false);
        Graphics.setColor(1,1, 1, 1);

        Graphics.setColor(1,1, 1, 1);
    }
}
```

GameObject.java

```
package com.icyrelic.game.object;

import com.icyrelic.game.Graphics.Animation;
import com.icyrelic.game.Graphics.Graphics;
import com.icyrelic.game.world.Location;
import lombok.Getter;



@Getter
public abstract class GameObject {


    protected Location location;

    protected float width = 1, height = 1;
    protected float xImageOffset = 0, yImageOffset = 0;

    protected Animation[] animations;
    protected int currentAnimation = 0;


    public GameObject(float x, float y, float width, float height, float rotation, float rotationOffset) {
        this.location = new Location(x, y, rotation, rotationOffset);
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;


    }

    public void render () {
        animations[currentAnimation].play();

        Graphics.setRotation(location.getRotation() + location.getRotationOffset());
        Graphics.drawImage(animations[currentAnimation].getImage(), location.getX(), location.getY(), xImageOffset, yImageOffset, width, height);
        Graphics.setRotation(0);

        //Graphics.setRotation(-rotation);





    }

    public abstract void update ();
}
```

After trying to translate the information provided by Alberto I have the following result. its somewhat closer in the right direction but still not 100%

```
        hitBox.setXOffset(((float) Math.sin(location.getRotationRadians()) ));
        hitBox.setYOffset(((float) Math.cos(location.getRotationRadians()) ));
```

[image]

Comment: might be a good starting point sharing your code?

Comment: I added the Hitbox and Bullet code. wasn't sure what exactly to share for this question so I hope what I shared is enough.

Comment: probably also `Projectile` is necessary

Comment: Added, also added GameObject.java which is inherited from projectile

Comment: where are you drawing the blue circle?

Comment: In projectile render function. But it is just a visual to be able to see HitBox. HitBox is what I am trying to rotate. Ive tried changing its offsets but that doesnt seem to work when the rotation changes away from 0.

Comment: Graphics.drawHollowCircle(location.getX() + hitBox.getXOffset(), location.getY() + hitBox.getYOffset(), hitBox.getRadius()); }

Comment: can't you do the same as you are doing in `Graphics.setRotation`?

Comment: I dont think so, im not technically drawing HitBox its just a circle with a centerpoint and a radius. I need to offset that Centerpoint but I assume the offset is going to need to change based on rotation.

Comment: sorry I don't understand, how can I get the center position of the projectile ?

Answer (score 0):

Since

```
Graphics.drawHollowCircle(location.getX() + hitBox.getXOffset(), location.getY() + hitBox.getYOffset(), hitBox.getRadius());
```

Is always drawing at the bottom, this

```
Graphics.drawHollowCircle(location.getX() + hitBox.getXOffset(), location.getY() + hitBox.getYOffset() / 2, hitBox.getRadius());
```

Should draw the circle in the center... then using some trigonometry, to get the center of the circle you will have to do something like this:

```
float offsetX = Math.sin(location.getRotation()) * (hitBox.getYOffset() / 2);
float offsetY = Math.cos(location.getRotation()) * (hitBox.getYOffset() / 2);

Graphics.drawHollowCircle(location.getX() + offsetX, location.getY()  + offsetY, hitBox.getRadius());
```

assuming `location.getRotation()` will return the radiants to rotate

Comment: So hitbox.getxoffset and getyoffset are 0 by default. the center of the circle is already known by location.getX and location.getY so using thiswould is just be the sin/cos of the radiant rotation?

Comment: I added an image with what im currently getting using cos and sin of the rotation

Comment: @IcyRelic what is returning `location.getRotation()`? my aim with `Graphics.drawHollowCircle(location.getX() + hitBox.getXOffset(), location.getY() + hitBox.getYOffset() / 2, hitBox.getRadius());`was to get the blue circle to draw in the center of the image, can you confirm this? however, the coordinates system chages based on the rendering system, therefore this might not work as expected, and so please confirm that with that line (and without sin/cos) the blue circle is in the center of all images

Comment: It was already drawing in the center if i removed my yOffset to draw it at the bottom. The x and y is center to the blue circle. So the offset you provided would just undo my offset i put. I was able to get the circle in almost the right position buy multiple the sin of rotation on the x by 0.12f and the cos of rotation on the y by -0.12  some of them depending on rotation are exactly where they should be and other rotations are slightly off.

Comment: @IcyRelic please try now... if it doesn't work, please post an image using `Graphics.drawHollowCircle(location.getX(), location.getY(), hitBox.getRadius());`